# How to autowire class in Maven multi module Spring web app?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on application which contains Maven multi module projects. When  tryng to @Autowire a service class from another module I'm  getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` What makes this project unique is the dependency is between 2 web modules.

**Parent Project**

---

Pom.xml

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.test.simple-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>module-x</module>
        <module>module-y</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Module X**

---

Pom.xml

```
<project>
    <artifactId>module-x</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
     <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
package com.test.module-x.service;      
@Service("userService")
   public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
}
```

**Module Y**

---

Pom.xml

```
<project>
    <artifactId>module-y</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.simpleproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-x</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

component-scan in Y

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.module-x.service" />
```

```
 @Controller
     public class SimpleController {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    }
```

Both modules are Spring mvc **web** projects (both pom.xml packaging is war)

Running the app throws  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/module-x/service/UserService`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/test/module-x/service/UserService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:846)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say unless you include more information - ideally some of the pom.xml - the war plugin in particular

Comment: More information is included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WAR module with a dependency on another WAR module does not have access to classes generated by the dependency module.  You will therefore have to provide the classes in `module-x` to those in `module-y`.  There are two ways to do it.

### Option 1: Cleaner design

---

Abstract out common classes into a separate JAR module and declare a dependency from both `module-x` and `module-y` to this module.

### Option 2: Get access to classes declared in `module-x` from classes in `module-y`

---

First, configure the `maven-war-plugin` in `module-x` to package the classes as a separate JAR file.

```
<project>
  <artifactId>module-x</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
          <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Now, declare a dependency on `module-x` in `module-y`:

```
<project>
  <artifactId>module-y</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module-x</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Tried option 2 but I'm getting the same error. Do you think it has something to do with component-scan.

Comment: If it is the same stacktrace, component scan has nothing do with it.  If it was a component scan error, there would be something like `No matching bean of type ... found`.  [Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/maven-multi-war) is a working sample.  Compare it with your code to find the differences that are causing the error.  If this does not work, post a full sample project that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create the sample project. I'm checking it, will let you know the result.

Comment: Just started working again on this project. The sample project you provided works fine but I changed pom.xml to support running the app on servers defined in eclipse and I'm getting 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:creating bean with name 'fooController' defined in file ...\...\FooController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.example.web.FooController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [org.example.web.FooController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on`

Answer (score 1):

You have to define, in the pom.xml file associated to the Module Y a dependency on the output war file of the Module X.
It is strange however to have 2 war files and place a dependency between them. You will have, to my understanding, 2 web applications. If I guess correctly, Module X is somehow the business layer of the whole system, (includes the services) so is enough to generate a jar file from it, and define only Module Y as a web module.
Nevertheless, you need to have an explicit maven dependency to Module X in the pom.xml file of Module Y.